# Visual Studio 2013: "No framework version is selected, you must select one before creating a project."

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, .net-framework-version

I've recently installed Visual Studio 2013 on my laptop (Windows 8.1) and I've ran into trouble when trying to create a project.

I'm prompted to select a framework version, but the list of frameworks is empty. See below picture.

[image: Empty]

As I've read [on msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/dotnet_sdks.aspx), the .NET framework version 4.5 should be included in Visual Studio 2013, but as you can see, it's not in my list of frameworks.

I've tried to install version 4.5.3 manually but the problem persists.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Downvoters please elaborate

Comment: same error, reinstalling didn't worked. Any helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uninstall Visual Studio then re install it from [Microsoft](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/whatsnew/) website

Comment: Really? It just took 2 hours to install from the official site!

Comment: You must have slow internet connection or slow pc. It took me 25 min to download and install.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was accidentally opening **VS 2015** instead of **VS 2019**

* I've already uninstalled **VS 2015** but it's still available to be opened, and showing this error when trying to create a project.