# Can't make new project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Yesterday I installed Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web on Windows 7 Home Premium. When I launched it and trying to set up new project, I wasn't able to do it, because no .Net framework was seen in New Project window. I got message "No framework is selected, you must select one before creating a project". Then I reinstalled twice Visual, but it didn't solve my problem. I also tried to install .Net 4.0 manually, but I got messsage that newer version is already installed, which means that .NET 4.5 framework was installed on my computer during Visual's installation. Is there any possible solution to my issue, beside reinstalling Windows? I would be very grateful for help.

Comment: You mean the dropdown is empty as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150395/visual-studio-2013-no-framework-version-is-selected-you-must-select-one-befor?

Comment: what you see in c:\windows\microsot.net library?

Comment: When I am trying to make new project dropdownlist with .NET frameworks is empty. As I wrote reinstallation didn't help.